# why is genisoimage output all caps?

Tags: kernel, compression

i ran this command

`genisoimage -o OS.iso dir_iso`

I have this input

```
dir_iso
    /boot
        /grub
            grub.cfg
        OS.bin
```

But getting

```
OS.iso
    /.              //note - don't know why this directory is coming, need help for this one also
    /BOOT
        /GRUB
            GRUB.CFG
        OS.BIN
```

How to fix?

**EDIT**

note that the contents of the files are not changed.

Comment: Not sure why you added the tag "kernel"?

Comment: I need to verify the output of my kernel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`genisoimage` creates ISO9660/Joliet/HFS file systems. You may have created an ISO9660 system, a common denominator that could be read by most hardware. Each file written to the ISO9660 filesystem must have a filename in the 8.3 format (up to 8 characters, period, up to 3 characters, all uppercase). Hence your caps.

`/.` symbolizes the current directory.

To allow longer file names and lowercase, you have to provide additonal command line options to have genisoimage create the additional filesystem metadata needed for Joliet, Rock Ridge or Apple ISO 9660, which are extensions on the restrictive ISO9660 file system allowing for long file names, extended characters and file permissions. Use the `-J` option to generate Joliet directory records (Unicode, allowing non-Latin scripts to be used), and/or `-R` to include the Rock Ridge extension (Unix-style permissions and longer names). See `man genisoimage` for all options.

Comment: Yes, but  want to prevent genisoimage from putting all filenames in uppercase

Comment: Question title sounds different. Still, I added some info on how to write long names.

Comment: Ok, I'll try "-j".

Comment: thanks alot @vanadium !

Comment: one small note for future readers, genisoimage said something about this "rock ridge". to solve it, use "-R".

Comment: Thank you! I included this in the answer, and clarified that we are adding extensions to the ISO format to support long names, etc.